# Как использовать подключенные через Gulp шрифты в проекте?

Tags: вёрстка, gulp

Ситуация такова. В сборке gulp есть таск, овтечающий за шрифты. Он отрабатывает нормально в сборке появляется папка с нужными файлами шрифтов. Но вопрос возник в другом-как их подключить к проекту? до работы с gulp я это делал например так

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />`

Но сейчас файлы стилей подключаются gulp-ом(незачем указывать ссылку) и я не совсем понимаю, как их прикрутитить к проекту.Как действовать в такой ситуации? Может их как и css\js файлы надо плагином `concat` объединить в 1 файл и в head прописать марщрут до его местонахождения?

Код таска, который собирает шрифты:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/*{ttf,woff,woff2,svg,eot}')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/src/fonts/'))
  gulp.src('./src/fonts/open_sans/*ttf')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/src/fonts/open_sans'))
});
```

Comment: Добавьте код таска, отвечающего за шрифты, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Mikl добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @Iga Вы пользуетесь sass препроцессором?

Comment: @Denisoed да, Sass

Comment: @Iga https://github.com/agragregra/optimizedhtml-start-template я думаю вам это больше поможет! Там все уже за вас сделано

Comment: @Denisoed Прекратите человеку кидать такого типа решения, человек не знает, как подключаются шрифты вообще.

Comment: @Denisoed спасибо за ссылку,но мне именно интересно самому поиграться с gulp и самому разобраться,что в нем и как.потому и решил сделать свой конфиг

Comment: @Iga Лучшего всего учится на примерах)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылку указывать все-равно надо. Просто ваш таск перекладывает файлы шрифтов в билд директорию `./build/src/fonts/`. И теперь вам надо указать относительный путь до шрифтов, там где вы их подключаете (в css, конечно), примерно так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontName';
  src: url('../fonts/fontName.eot');
  src:  url('../fonts/fontName.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/fontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/fontName.svg') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/fontName.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Раньше, строго говоря, вы тоже подключали не шрифты, а css файл со шрифтами.

Comment: то есть в head на каждый файл open_sans'a надо прописать ссылку?
код,который вы привели можно исопльзовать в sass?

Comment: Лучше создать отдельный css файл для шрифтов `fonts.css`, там все это прописать и подключить его к вашему сайту. Можно в head, но я думаю, вам стоит, настроить сборку ваших css с помощью gulp.

Comment: не совсем понял.вот текущий конфиг гульпа, с которым я работаю.https://github.com/jokep5/Simple-gulp-config  вы предлагаете при сборке брать все файлы шрифтов,делать конкатеннацию и прописывать их в один .css файл?

Comment: Не-не-не Дэвид Блэйн! Как подключаются шрифты? - они прописыватся в css. Для этого указывается путь до шрифта в css. Что делает ваш gulp - он перекладывает шрифты из одной папки в другую. Значит вам надо, всего лишь, правильно указать новые пути в вашем css. [http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face)

Comment: Заработало.Спасибо)